# Order of evaluation of [in]equality operator in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

What is the order of evaluation of the equality operator in C++ ?

I see many code examples like [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted_until)

```
template <class ForwardIt, class Compare>
ForwardIt is_sorted_until(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, Compare comp) 
{
    if (first != last) {
        ForwardIt next = first;
        while (++next != last) {
            if (comp(*next, *first))
                return next;
            first = next;
        }
    }
    return last;
}
```

and in the `while (++next != last)`
 - is the left side evaluated before the right side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order is unspecified, [like most binary operators in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order). It's perfectly legal for the compiler to evaluate `++next` or `last` first, so if `next` and `last` were references to the same underlying variable, you'd be entering undefined behavior territory (in this case, there is no problem).