# Different result from std::vector erase when comparing in if than comparing to stored value

Tags: c++, libstdc++, comparison-operators, erase-remove-idiom, qcc

For some reason, I get different result when comparing the return value from `vector::erase` inside a `if` statement or if I store the value first and then compare. But it seems to only happen with g++.

This is  built on Ubuntu 20.04 AMD64 using g++, libstdc++ and with `-std=c++14` flag.
`g++ -std=c++14 foo.cpp && ./a.out`

This will return `false`

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{0, 1, 8, 3, 8, 5, 8, 7,8, 9};
    int thing_id{9};

    std::vector<int>::iterator const cit{
        std::remove_if(v.begin(),
                        v.end(),
                        [thing_id](int const& thing) -> bool {
                            return thing == thing_id;
                        })};

    if (v.erase(cit, v.cend()) == v.cend()) {
        std::cout << "true\n";
        return true;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "false\n";
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will return `true`

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{0, 1, 8, 3, 8, 5, 8, 7,8, 9};
    int thing_id{9};

    std::vector<int>::iterator const cit{
        std::remove_if(v.begin(),
                        v.end(),
                        [thing_id](int const& thing) -> bool {
                            return thing == thing_id;
                        })};

    auto const prev_end = v.erase(cit, v.cend());
    if (prev_end == v.cend()) {
        std::cout << "true\n";
        return true;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "false\n";
        return false;
    }
}
```

When building for QNX ARM64 with QCC and libc++, both snippets will return `true`.

Why is this? Should not the comparisons be deterministic either or? Can someone please explain to me what is going on here?

Comment: On a side note: since your `vector` elements are simple `int`s and not objects, You can simplify your use of `std::remove_if()` by using `std::remove()` instead, you don't need the lambda at all, eg: `std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), thing_id);`

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm aware. But the example is a simplified version of a more complex code base where we have objects being compared. I just wanted to keep it as close as possible to the original code without having to add a struct or class in the example. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When [`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) succeeds, it invalidates iterators (and references) to the elements at or after the point of the erasure. Thus the `end()` iterator gets invalidated as well. In other words, after the erasure will succeed, the vector will have the new `cend()`.

This is important because the order of evaluation of the comparison operator is unspecified, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56349439/1458097). In other words, given the expression `v.erase(cit, v.cend()) == v.cend()`, the compiler is free to decide to evaluate the rightmost `v.cend()` first, remember it, and only then evaluate the return value of `v.erase(cit, v.cend())`. In such a case, it would be comparing the newly returned past-the-end iterator value to the old `v.cend()` value (i.e., before it got invalidated by the erasure).

Comment: Ah. I see. Yes, that makes sense.

So I guess there might be a subtle difference between the implementation in libc++ vs libstdc++? Or in how comparison operator works when compiled with qcc?

Comment: When changing the one line comparison to `if (v.cend() == v.erase(cit, v.cend()))` it also started returning true. But that would still not be guaranteed to always work like that?

Comment: I doubt it depends on the library implementation. I think more likely some compilers just tend to reorder certain invocations for whatever "optimization" reasons they might detect. Don't rely on the order of evaluation in cases where the C++ standard does not specify it. Sometimes it is explicitly specified, for example, the so-called _short-circuit evaluation_ of built-in `&&` and `||` is guaranteed, but in general, it is not.

Comment: BTW, the [tag:c++14] tag should only be used along with the more general [tag:c++] tag (so the people interested in C++ and watching the corresponding general tag would find your question).

Comment: Mkay... Changed my tags. 